# Help me solve this polynomial problem

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

I have to find $a$,$b$ and $c$ so that this expression is a polynomial:

$$\frac{x^3+ax^2+bx+c}{x-1} + \frac{x^3+bx^2+cx+a}{x-2} + \frac{x^3+cx^2+ax+b}{x-3}$$

Please give me hints. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint**: $x^3 + ax^2 + bx + c$ must have a root at $1$. This is because $(x - 1)$ must be a divisor of $x^3 + ax^2 + bx + c$, or else there would be a term involving the quantity $\frac{1}{x - 1}$. In a similar manner, $x^3 + bx^2 + cx + a$ has a root at $2$ and $x^3 + cx^2 + ax + b$ has a root at $3$. This gives us three equations, the first of which is

$$1 + a + b + c = 0$$

Now use this to determine $a, b, c$.

Comment: Does it matter if the numerators are different? xD

Comment: @A6Tech Yes, it does - I missed that originally. I've edited my answer now, thank you.

Comment: Yeah, I see now. Thanks a lot :D

Answer (score 1):

Divide with a remainder:
$$
\frac{x^3+ax^2+bx+c}{x-1}= x^2+b'x+c' +\frac{p}{x-1}  
$$
and similarly for other summands. Then your question is reduced to the next one: when
$$
\frac{p}{x-1}  +\frac{q}{x-2}  +\frac{r}{x-3}  
$$
is a polynomial? The answer: only for $p=q=r=0$, since the quadratic polynomial 
$$
p(x-2)(x-3)+q(x-1)(x-3)+r(x-2)(x-1)
$$
cannot be divided by $(x-1)(x-2)(x-3)$. Hence $x^3+ax^2+bx+c$ is divided by $x-1$ etc.